# how to automatically invoke a method in android?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

im building an android application that recive images from arduino uno in order to show them continously as a video , i write an asyncTask that reads image and show it in image view , how can i invoke this method every seconed automatically .
here is my asyncTask
I made a button that invoke the async task , but how to make it invoked continously

```
class myAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> 
{
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        mmInStream = tmpIn;
        int byteNo;
        try {
            byteNo = mmInStream.read(buffer);
            if (byteNo != -1) {
                //ensure DATAMAXSIZE Byte is read.
                int byteNo2 = byteNo;
                int bufferSize = 7340;
                int i = 0;
                while(byteNo2 != bufferSize){
                    i++;
                    bufferSize = bufferSize - byteNo2;
                    byteNo2 = mmInStream.read(buffer,byteNo,bufferSize);
                    if(byteNo2 == -1){
                        break;
                    }
                    byteNo = byteNo+byteNo2;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        bm1 = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
        image.setImageBitmap(bm1);
    }
}
```

Comment: ever heard of a `while loop?` better yet use a `timer`

Comment: use handler http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's from a background thread, one possibility is to use an unbounded for loop. For example, suppose the AsyncTask currently does:

```
private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<T1, Void, T3>
{
     protected T3 doInBackground(T1... value)
     {
         return longThing(value);
     }

     protected void onPostExecute(T3 result)
     {
         updateUI(result);
     }
 }
```

then rewrite it as something like:

```
private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<T1, T3, T3>
{
     protected T3 doInBackground(T1... value)
     {
         for (;;)
         {
             T3 result = longThing(value);
             publishProgress(result);
             Thread.sleep(1000);
         }

         return null;
     }

     protected void onProgressUpdate(T3... progress)
     {
         updateUI(progress[0]);
     }
 }
```

Of course, you should have a check to break the loop (for example when the Activity is paused or destroyed).

Another option is to create a [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) instance and call postDelayed() repeatedly.

Comment: a made abutton when i click it i will receive images , this forloop will but me in a not ended thread , what if i need to use the interface and click in athor buttons

Comment: That's why I said "if it's from a background thread" :) Obviously it should NOT be used from the UI thread.

Comment: what should i do then ?

Comment: I extended the example, hope it's helpful.

Comment: thank u very much , but i need to update the image view each time i read an image , after that i need to read another image automatically , i write an asyncTask that read an image from onput stream , but i dont know how to continously execute this asyntask .

Comment: That's more or less the example that I wrote :) longThing() would be downloadImage() and updateUI() would be updateImageView(). Instead of continuously firing AsyncTasks, just fire a single one. But anyway, I think the Handler answer would be better in this case...

Comment: are you sure about  publishProgress(result); its alwayes give me an error

Answer (score 0):

```
Handler h = new Handler();
h.postDelayed(r, DELAY_IN_MS);
Runnable r = new new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        // Do your stuff here
        h.postDelayed(this, DELAY_IN_MS);
    }
}
```